# Attach Handler Only Once Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this has been addressed before, but I could use some clarification and maybe an update.

I have a jQuery handler like:

```
$(document).on("submit", $(".validform"), function(e) {

. . . .

});
```

There does seem to be a problem sometimes when the form element is submitted multiple times and it looks like the hanlder is either firing multiple times or there are multiple instances of the handler that are firing.

I tried using .one, and that works once, but then doesn't fire anymore.  I would like to attach the handler once and keep it attached while not attaching multiple instances.  This seems that it can be a problem in general with jQuery in this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: this `$(".validform")` should be `".validform"`

Comment: [jquery off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: how is the form being submitted? Cant you just hide the submit button after being triggered?

Comment: There would only be multiple instances of the handler attached if you ran the `.on()` statement multiple times, in which case jQuery is doing what it is supposed to (because multiple handlers is a valid thing). The solution is to *not* do that.

Comment: @nnnnnn could it be that he has multiple forms with the classname `validform`?

Comment: never mind this

Comment: How about hiding the submit button after click? Never mind this too, since after a browser refresh it would restore it.

Comment: What if you sent them to another page after clicking the submit?

Answer (score -1):

This maybe seems to work:

```
$(document).on("submit", ".validform", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var formdata = $(e.target).serialize();
  var rempass = $.post($(e.target).attr("action"), formdata);
  rempass.done(function(data) {
    // alert("test");
    $(".modal-body").html(data);
  });
$(".validform").off();
});
```

Comment: maybe means, is this working or not. do not put may be answers. if it works fine then put.

Comment: one. works, but it does just that.  It only fires once.  If they submit the form again it doesn't capture and the form is submitted conventionally.